# When i used String.Split the subsequent array only contains the first value?

Tags: c#

After reading a text file, I pass the information through a method that splits the string to get the required information for each field. I have gotten to the point where i split the string based on new lines, but it is beyond me why when I display the subsequent array (or list it's converted to), it only shows the first half of the first split string.

An example of how the input string looks:

```
ASSIGNMENT    
In-Class Test    02/07/2014     
In-Class Test    21/04/2013
```

Find my code below (the `numLines` variable was to simply see if it was being split into the correct number of lines as it should)

```
private void assignmentfinder(string brief, string id)
{   
    string searchcrit = "ASSIGNMENT";
    string assignment = brief.Substring(brief.IndexOf(searchcrit) + searchcrit.Length);
    string[] assignmentsplit;
    assignmentsplit = assignment.Split('\t');
    List<string> Assign = new List<string>(assignmentsplit);
    listBox2.DataSource = Assign;
    int numLines = assignment.Split('\n').Length;
    richTextBox1.Lines=(assignmentsplit);
}
```

The output I get is:

```
In-Class Test     
02/07/2014
```

Whereas it should show the second string split as well. Any ideas?

Comment: The one and only idea here is to debug your code step by step.

Comment: Try to remove the "assignmentSplit" parameter from the List<string> constructor. My guess is that you constrain the list to a lesser quantity of items than the expected.

Comment: What is the desired output? It is unclear to me exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Crowcoder Its not for me. Its just `string[] { "In-Class Test", "02/07/2014", "In-Class Test", "21/04/2013" }`.

Comment: @Crowcoder I want to have each line of input string separated so i can store the type of test and the date to be pulled into a text box

Comment: Replace `assignment.Split('\t')` with `Regex.Replace(assignment, Environment.NewLine, "");`

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you split for each tab (`\t`). Split for the new line as you say:

```
private void assignmentfinder(string brief, string id)
{
    string searchcrit = "ASSIGNMENT";
    string assignment = brief.Substring(brief.IndexOf(searchcrit) + searchcrit.Length);

    string[] assignmentSplit = assignment.Split('\n'); // splitting at new line

    richTextBox1.Lines = assignmentSplit;

    listBox2.DataSource = assignmentSplit.ToList();
}
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Just fixed a huge mistake

**Question:** Is it on purpose that the string `id` is never used?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the value of "brief" variable. Make sure the value you are putting in "brief" variable, actually conains "\n" and "\t".

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex like this:

```
private void assignmentfinder(string brief, string id)
{
    Regex rgxLines = new Regex(@"^(.*?)[ \t]+([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    MatchCollection mLines = rgxLines.Matches(brief);

    foreach (Match match in mLines)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += String.Format("Test: {0}{1}Date: {2}{1}{1}", 
                                            match.Groups[1].Value, 
                                            Environment.NewLine, 
                                            match.Groups[2].Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq to split on new line, then on tab, skipping the first line then aggregate into a list of string:

```
string brief = @"ASSIGNMENT
In-Class Test   02/07/2014
In-Class Test   21/04/2013";

List<string> theLines = new List<string>();     
var lines = brief.Split('\n').Skip(1).Select (b => b.Split('\t'));
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {
        theLines.Add(line[i]);
    }
}
```